# Data is not being deleted Ajax

Tags: php, ajax

When I clicked on the sil button, "Are you sure you want to delete it?" When I click on the message, a blank message page comes up and the data is not deleted.

```
(document).ready(function(){

     var productTable = $('#product_data').bootgrid({
      ajax: true,
      rowSelect: true,
      post: function()
      {
      },
      url: "fetch.php",
      formatters: {
       "commands": function(column, row)
       {
           var link="";
          /*  
            1001 => "siparis_toplubaski"  
            1002 => "siparis_ana" 
            1003 => "siparis_cokluforma"  
            1004 => "siparis_digitalbaski"   
            1005 => "siparis_etiket"  
            1006 => "siparis_matbuu"   
            1007 => "siparis_ofset"
          */


           if(row.formid==1001){
               link="siparis_toplubaski.php?DAID="+row.Id;
           }else if(row.formid==1002){
               link="siparis_ana.php?DAID="+row.Id;
           }else if(row.formid==1003){
               link="siparis_cokluforma.php?DAID="+row.Id;
           }else if(row.formid==1004){
               link="siparis_digitalbaski.php?DAID="+row.Id;
           }else if(row.formid==1005){
               link="siparis_etiket.php?DAID="+row.Id;
           }else if(row.formid==1006){
               link="siparis_matbuu.php?DAID="+row.Id;
           }else if(row.formid==1007){
               link="siparis_ofset.php?DAID="+row.Id;
           }


        return "<a href='"+link+"' type='button' class='btn btn-warning btn-xs update' data-row-id='"+row.Id+"'>Düzenle</a>" + 
        "&nbsp; <button type='button' class='btn btn-danger btn-xs delete' data-row-id='"+row.Id+"'>Sil</button>"

       }
      }
     });


     $(document).on("loaded.rs.jquery.bootgrid", function()
     {
       productTable.find(".delete").on("click", function(event)
      {
       if(confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this?"))
       {
        var Id = $(this).data("+row.Id+");
        $.ajax({
         url:"delete.php",
         method:"POST",
         data:{Id:Id},
         success:function(data)
         {
          alert(data);
          $('#product_data').bootgrid('reload');
         }
        })
       }
       else{
        return false;
       }
      });
      });    
     });
```

This is delete.php

```
<?php
//delete.php
include("connection.php");
if(isset($_POST["product_id"]))
{
 $query = "DELETE FROM siparis_ana WHERE Id = '".$_POST["id"]."'";
 if(mysqli_query($connection, $query))
 {
  echo 'Data Deleted';
 }
}
?>
```

Comment: i would start debugging with `print_r($_POST);` in delete.php, you will need to user browser console,network tab to see results

Comment: As you state you are new to coding, please take time to read [about SQL injection](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) for your and your end user's security. **Also** it would probably be a good idea to [`require connection.php`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.require.php).